# SQL: How can I combine a two separate values into one count

Tags: sql, count

**Scenario:** I have a table `Browsers` which is populated every time a browser is opened along with the associated date:

```
BrowserName                Date
-------------------------------------
Firefox?                   8/20/2017
Firefox                    8/20/2017
Google Chrome              8/20/2017
Google Chrome              8/20/2017
Google Chrome              8/20/2017
Opera                      8/20/2017
Internet Explorer          8/20/2017
Internet Explorer          8/20/2017
```

If I did a count as such:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (BrowserName) AS [Count Of Uses],
    BrowserName AS [Browser],
    Date
FROM 
    BROWSERS
GROUP BY 
    Date, BrowserName
```

I get a result something like this:

```
Count Of Uses       Browser             Date
--------------------------------------------------
       1            Firefox?            8/20/2017
       1            Firefox             8/20/2017
       3            Google Chrome       8/20/2017
       2            Internet Explorer   8/20/2017
       1            Opera               8/20/2017
```

**Question:** notice how there are two entries for `Firefox` (`Firefox` and `Firefox?`). How can I combine those into one count for `Firefox`, so that my end result would be like this:

```
Count Of Uses       Browser             Date
--------------------------------------------------
       2            Firefox             8/20/2017
       3            Google Chrome       8/20/2017
       2            Internet Explorer   8/20/2017
       1            Opera               8/20/2017
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
SELECT Date,
       (CASE WHEN BrowserName LIKE 'Firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
             ELSE BrowserName
        END) as Browser,
       COUNT(*) AS [Count Of Uses]
FROM BROWSERS
GROUP BY Date,
         (CASE WHEN BrowserName LIKE 'Firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
               ELSE BrowserName
          END) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answers, @Gordon Linoff, Can I just add more cases if there are more than one case? And if so what would be the best say to structure it?

Comment: @Techno04335 . . . You can add as many `WHEN` clauses as you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to handle this particular case:

```
SELECT
  COUNT (*) AS [Count Of Uses],
  replace(BrowserName, 'FireFox?', 'Firefox') AS [Browser],
  Date
FROM BROWSERS
GROUP BY 2,3
```

If you have multiple similar variations, nest `replace()` calls:

```
replace(replace(BrowserName, 'FireFox?', 'Firefox'), 'Internet Exploder', 'Internet Explorer') AS [Browser]
```

Comment: how would I handle this if I have multiple cases?

Comment: @tech it depends on what your multiple case are. Eg it could be that multiple browser names with `?` at the end, or it could be that the first 5 characters are the same, or something else. Each will have its own solution. This solution is hard coded to work for your specific example, but it’s also a simple solution (which is always preferable). What did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle ? in general

```
declare @T table (browser varchar(40), dt date);
insert into @T values 
      ('Firefox?', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Firefox', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Google Chrome', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Google Chrome', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Google Chrome?', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Opera', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Internet Explorer', '8/20/2017')
    , ('Internet Explorer',' 8/20/2017')
    , ('Internet Explorer', '8/21/2017')
    , ('Internet Explorer',' 8/21/2017');
with cte as 
( select t.dt, t.browser  
       , SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.browser),1,1) as f 
       , case when SUBSTRING(reverse(t.browser), 1, 1) = '?' then substring(t.browser, 1, LEN(t.browser ) -1) else t.browser end as browserT
    from @T t 
) 
select cte.dt as [date], cte.browserT as browswer, count(*) as [count]
from cte
group by cte.dt, cte.browserT 
order by cte.dt, cte.browserT;
```